# Save all object with th:object

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I want to sent object with model.addAttribute and get all object's variable after saving.

**Controller**

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/passport/details/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public String passportDetails(Model model, @PathVariable(name = "id") Long id) {
        PassportRequest passportRequest = businessService.getPassportRequestById(id);
        model.addAttribute("passport", passportRequest);
        return "/user/passport/create";
    }
    @PostMapping(value = "/passport/save")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public String savePassport(PassportRequest passport) {
        businessService.savePassportRequest(passport);
        return "redirect:/passport/details/" + passport.getId();
    }
```

**html-code:**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" th:action="@{/passport/save}"
                  data-parsley-validate="" role="form"
                  novalidate="" th:object="${passport}" id="sign-form">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{stage}"> 
    <div class="col-6 m-input-group">
         <label>Кем командирован</label>
         <input type="text" name="postedBy" placeholder="Введите" th:field="*{postedBy}" required>
    </div> 
</form
```

The problem is I need to make `<input type="hidden" th:field="*{objectVariable}"></input>` to every variable to send them. Is there any easier way to do?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is annotating your controller with `@SessionAttributes("passport")` (which means it will store the object on the session and keep all it's properties during this controllers methods).

You might also need to change

`public String savePassport(PassportRequest passport) {`

to

`public String savePassport(@ModelAttribute("passport") PassportRequest passport) {`

to make sure all the attributes line up.